# How does share consolidation impact options?

Tags: options, put-options

[image]

Kinder Morgan Canada did a share consolidation that took effect today.  I see there are still options out there that reflect the unconsolidated price.  Would someone buying the put option after the consolidation be able to take advantage of the large price drop or are there protections in place that prevent sale of options when a share consolidation occurs?

Comment: As a side note I'm not set up to trade options myself so if this an actual opportunity have at it.

Answer (score 1):

> Would someone buying the put option after the consolidation be able to take advantage of the large price drop or are there protections in place that prevent sale of options when a share consolidation occurs?

No - there is no arbitrage opportunity here. In the event of a corporate action like a split or consolidation, the exchange will adjust the quantity and strike of any outstanding options to reflect the new stock price.

So if a stock was trading at $10 and you had a $12 call option contract on 100 shares, then splits to a price of $5, your call option will be adjusted by the exchange to two $6 call option for a total of 200 shares. So the overall value will not change, since the price and strike will be halved and the quantity doubled.

If your broker is still listing the old strikes, it's possible that they haven't adjusted their data to the new share price.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the exchange will scale both options that had been purchased as well as those currently for sale?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "for sale" but any existing offers (bid/ask) should be adjusted as well. I suspect your broker just hasn't reflected that yet.

Comment: If the stock is at $10 and you own  a $12 call on 100 shares and the stock splits 2:1, the strike price halves and the number of contracts doubles.  The contract does not go to 200 shares.

Comment: DS:  YW.  @Myles - the exchange will adjust options that existed before the corporate action.  After it, new option contracts will be standardized and will have nothing to do with the corporate action.

Comment: @BobBaerker Lag in the adjustment through the brokerage seems to create ugly pitfalls.  In this example if I offer a bad strike price on the day before consolidation (let's say $7), it may look good for a few hours the next day until it adjusts down to $3.50.

Comment: @Myles - No, it doesn't work that way.  The stock split (or other corporate event) occurs after the market has closed and the option adjustment occurs simultaneously.

Comment: @BobBaerker In the photo attached to my post we see both put and call options at a $17 strike price after the market value is down to $5.  I created this post to try to make sense of that.

Comment: @BobBaerker If they only look like $17 for now and will be adjusted down to ~$5 later that's fine but they are obviously not adjusted yet.  If I had wrote an offer at $6 and at $17 last week neither would appear adjusted yet however the $6 may look legit...

Comment: You're providing snippets of price information and comments out of context so there's no way to explain what you are seeing.  It is impossible that you could buy a $17 put for $1.40 when share price is $5.00 so it has to be an adjusted option.  If you were to provide the closing share price on the day before the corporate event and the details of the corporate event then some sense could be made of this.  Without that, none.

Comment: @Myles Brokers will also sometimes leave the option name as is, but these are designated NS(nonstandard) and still show along the pre-split price. These are still tradable, and there is probably only minimal arbitrage to be found here (as provided by pricing bots if at all) the actual shares exchanged will reflect a post-split amount. So if the shares split 1-2, you would receive 50 shares per option on execution instead of the usual 100. End result being the same as if the shares were received pre-split, and then split occurs.

Comment: @BobBaerker Checking that I don't think I have much hope in understanding what is going on.  Overnight Thursday shares dropped from~$44 to ~$16 based on a 3 to 1 consolidation.  Then over the weekend shares dropped down to ~$5 based on a $11.40 special distribution to the parent company.  So I'm guessing these offers at the $17 strike price can only have been created on Friday however with two events so close together that really muddies the waters with how investors would know what the scaling factor from adjustment would be.

Comment: Unfortunately the "special distribution" does _not_ affect current options. Anyone that held a $17 call ($51 before the split) was screwed...

Comment: @D Stanley - Why do you believe that anyone that held a $17 call is screwed?

Comment: Screwed may be an overstatement - if you own a $17 call and the stock drops to $6 because the company sent $11 to the parent company, your call is now worthless.

Comment: That said, it doesn't fit the quotes shown, so maybe there's something _else_ going on.

Comment: Well fuck, definitely something really wonky going on with the price for the stock.  It's back up to ~$15 and the shares that I bought yesterday at ~$5 are no longer in my portfolio.  Without understanding of what is happening to the share price I really can't use this situation to work on my understanding of options.

Comment: Myles, you have stepped into the Twilight Zone of options where nothing appears to be what it seems.  Options are hard enough for most people to understand but special dividends are the coup to grace if the options are adjusted. Speaking of which, see next comment.

Comment: Disclaimer: This is a Canadian stock so I have no access to the details of the option adjustment. Therefore, I can only base my answer on US options which I am familiar with. Based on one of the ways in which a special dividend is handled by the OCC, my guess is that the $11.40 special dividend has been attached to the KML option.  When you adjust the $17 strike by that amount, the quotes make sense.  So a $17 put is effectivle  a $5.60 put.  For a US example of this, Google (PCH2 OCC special dividend) and you'll see how the $3.54 Potlatchdeltic spec dividend has been attached to the options.

Comment: @BobBaerker Would this be treated like a special dividend? Since it's not a return to _shareholders_ but to the parent company I was assuming it wouldn't affect options (since it's _not_ a wash to shareholders).

Comment: About 6 comments up, Myles mentioned a $11.40 spec div.  That would go to shareholders. Based on that, if attached to the option, it makes sense. The $17 put buyer has the right to sell the stock for $17 but has to deliver shares worth $5 plus $11.40.  IOW, it's as if it was a $5.60 strike and the stock is 60 cents ITM.  Let's try this.  Suppose KML was $5.40 and the strikes Myles posted were $6 strike (60 cents ITM) instead of $17. Would the quotes ($1.00 $1.40 $1.70 for puts) in the chart then make sense? What Myles needs is an equiv to the OCC site that explains adjustments for corp actions

Comment: "based on a $11.40 special distribution ***to the parent company***."

Comment: Distribution to a certain class of shares which are held by the parent company I think.  However based on the price suddenly bouncing back up by about 200% it seems that that got undone maybe...

Comment: Honestly my bigger concern right now is that my balance is down the cost of these shares that mysteriously tripled in value overnight and yet I don't have them in my portfolio to realize that gain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't  the details of your share consolidation so I can't answer your specific question about Kinder Morgan Canada. My guess is that you are seeing some adjusted and unadjused options.

Option contracts are adjusted when there is a  significant corporate event affecting the underlying stock.  Examples are a stock split, reverse stock split, merger, acquisition, special dividend, spin-off, etc.. When one of these events, the option is altered to reflect the changes.

The simplest event is the stock split.

- 2 for 1: You get 2x as many contracts with a strike price of 1∕2 the original strike price
- 3 for 1: You get 3x as many contracts with a strike price of 1∕3 the original strike price
- 3 for 2: You have the same number of  contracts with a strike price of  2∕3 the original strike price  and the multiplier changes from 100 to 150
- 1 for 5 reverse split: No change to strike price or multiplier and the delivery becomes 20 shares

The adjustments  get more complex as the terms of the corporate event get more complex. Here's an example of how the OCC handles it (US options):

https://www.theocc.com/components/docs/market-data/infomemos/2009/jan/25361.pdf

One thing is for sure when these occur.  There is no arbitrage opportunity.  There  is no free money.  All of the changes in the underlying are accounted for in the options after adjustments are made.

What can be confusing is that after a corporate event such as a special dividend, new standard contracts are issued and their terms are very different from the adjusted contracts.

Some tip offs that a contract may be adjusted:

- the option seems much too cheap or too expensive
- there are two different option symbols with the same month and strike price
- the abbreviation “ADJ” appears in the option's description
- a number such as 1 or 2 is added as a suffix to the underlying stock symbol.